# How to find frequency of use during the week

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have lots of data spanning from 2022-01 to 2023-05. I am trying to get the date from the time stamp and pair it with the appropriate member type. The data I am using looks like this:

| started_at | member_casual |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-05 10:05:43 | member |
| 2022-06-04 13:12:22 | casual |
| 2023-05-04 11:15:32 | member |

The code I tried is:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM(
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM started_at) AS day_of_week,
    CASE
    WHEN day_of_week = 1 THEN 'Sunday'
    WHEN day_of_week = 2 THEN 'Monday'
    WHEN day_of_week = 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
    WHEN day_of_week = 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
    WHEN day_of_week = 5 THEN 'Thursday'
    WHEN day_of_week = 6 THEN 'Friday'
    WHEN day_of_week = 7 THEN 'Saturday'
    ELSE weekday
    FROM 
      `table`
    )
GROUP BY
member_casual
```

I am trying to find out how often, during the week, do the members and casual users use this product, however, when I run this code I keep getting a flag. I get a flag for the FROM clause in the subquery, but wouldnt I need that from so that the query pulls the info from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%A', started_at) AS DoW,
    SUM(IF(member_casual = 'member', 1, 0)) AS Members,
    SUM(IF(member_casual = 'casual', 1, 0)) AS Casuals
FROM `table`
GROUP BY DoW;
```

For reference: [Format elements for date and time parts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried that code and it said that the **SUM** function couldn't work on the boolean string **member_casual**. So I added a subquery that used **CAST** to make **member_casual** to a float64. Then I got another warning that said that **started_at** in the Format_Date function is not a recognized name.

Comment: I don't know how you made your code look like that, bc every time I use ` or ``` it won't show my code like that. However, here is the code:                                                                       ```SELECT 
    FORMAT_DATE('%W', started_at) AS DoW,
    SUM(member_casual = 'member') AS Members,
    SUM(member_casual = 'casual') AS Casuals
FROM (
  SELECT
    member_casual,
    CAST(member_casual AS float64)
  FROM
`table`
)
GROUP BY DoW;```

Comment: sorry, i'm from mysql world, so some syntax may vary. try this:
instead of:

    `member_casual = 'member'`

put this:

    `IF(member_casual = 'member', 1, 0)`

...and have a look at this page also ;-) [Learn more about formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Yes! that does indeed work. That pulls up how many casual users VS members used this during each week of the year. How would I pull up how many used it during each day of the week?

Comment: I accidently figured that one out. I changed the `%W` to `%A` and it worked. What are those, the `%W` and `%A` do or mean?

Comment: [Format elements for date and time parts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I took an incorrect format argument. Edited

Comment: Thanks for all the help man! I will definitely use those format elements in my code now. Also, thank you for showing me the reference page for big query, now I will be able to look up solutions easier.